# Add to Cart controls quanitity text not showing

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

For some reason, I cannot get the text for quantity number to show when someone ones to add a product to cart. When you click the (+) or (-) buttons, no number shows to let the person know how many items they have selected. I have tried changing text color/background but to no avail. I'm thinking maybe the text and background color is the same? I am really stumped here. Any input is appreciated.

You can see what I'm talking about via a product page: http://museiam.ca/product/woman-dress-for-men/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is there - it is a margin problem. It is located in your theme's css file (style.css:Line 4851). You will want to remove the margin (The 6th element).

```
.quantity input.qty, #content .quantity input.qty {
    width: 48px !important;
    height: 50px !important;
    line-height: 50px !important;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    /* margin: 0 0 0 35px; <-- REMOVE THIS LINE */
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0 !important;
    border-left: 1px solid #4d4d4d !important;
    border-right: 1px solid #4d4d4d !important;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0 !important;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0 !important;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0 !important;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0 !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 0 !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 0 #f7f6f7 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 0 #f7f6f7 !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 0 #f7f6f7 !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px !important;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px !important;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px !important;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px !important;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

[image: Screenshot of fixed solution]

Comment: Hello. I removed that line yet the problem still persists. Any ideas? Thx!

Comment: After adding margin-left:35px I got it to sit in the proper place. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction